# Jboss log4j SMTP appender sending one lin of stack trace in per email

Tags: jboss, smtp, log4j, appender

I'm using the SMTP appender in jboss-log4j.xml to send errors via email, sometimes it just gets crazy and start sending one line of stack trace per email and the email traffic. becomes very high because of this

How can I prevent this to happen is there any config option for this or is this jut a bug in jboss log4?

My conf for the appender:

```
 <appender name="SMTP" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
     <param name="To" value="email to"/>
     <param name="From" value="email from"/>
     <param name="Subject" value="SUBJECT"/>
     <param name="SMTPHost" value="localhost"/>
     <param name="BufferSize" value="10"/>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ABSOLUTE},%c{1}] %m%n"/>
     </layout>
   </appender>
```

Comment: OK, Dan. Won't happen again. It's just that "SMPT" is my most favourite typo in my own stuff, too. :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't want to bother you. I actually thought that those are handled by the creator of a question himself... Its my third day on the platform.

Comment: @brainbowler see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work

Answer (score 1):

The buffer size is set pretty small, try changing the buffer size to 512